# How to get the data never completed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a data in my sql table of customers call details where one number are multiple times and some not connected or drooped first time but second time they were connected so i want to get only that data that never connected

example:
this is actually data

```
Customer_Number        Status
123                    dropped
456                    connected
789                    dropped
123                    connected
456                    connected
789                    dropped
789                    not connected
```

And I want to get data like this:

```
Customer_Number          Status
789                      dropped
```

Comment: There is now way of knowing the sequence of events from the sample data published. IS there a timestamp or something else which could establish soe?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should display only those Customer_number which were never connected. The query concatenate all the statuses for each customer number and display only those number for which connection_status was never contain "connected"

```
select Customer_Number, group_concat(DISTINCT status) as connection_status 
from customers
GROUP BY Customer_Number
HAVING connection_status = 'dropped,not connected' OR connection_status='not connected,dropped'
```

Comment: I edit my question with another status that is "not connected" I want to show that data also that status is "not connected"...

Comment: Your query show all data that is never connected but not showing that is "not connected" is query only showing the data that status is only dropped but I want to show the data that status is "not connected", I hope you get what I want.., Please help me...

Comment: @TarunPandat Can you please upvote and accept my answer bro.